# m2e connector for jaxws-maven-plugin download issue

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jax-ws, m2eclipse

I am getting the below error while trying to download m2e connector for jaxws-maven-plugin from eclipse market place

Unable to read repository at https://coderplus.github.io/m2e-connector-for-jaxws-maven-plugin/content.xml.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 2):

I was also unable to install the plugin by importing automatically the plugin on eclipse with the discover new connector it gave me the same error. I think this is because https://coderplus.github.io/m2e-connector-for-jaxws-maven-plugin/content.xml doesn't exist and return a 404 error. So the error is a bit misleading because importing the certificate in the java truststore will lead to the same error.

My solution was to install the plugin with the Help > Install New Software menu. In the work with input box I've entered the following url : "https://coderplus.github.io/m2e-connector-for-jaxws-maven-plugin/" (no content.xml at end) and hit enter, it has shown the plugin and the install process comes to the end with this method. After restarting I still had a problem with my pom but hitting the discover new connector worked then (it had probably installed what was missing)

**Edit 18/01/2019 :** 
As I've reinstalled a new eclipse I get this error again even if I installed the new m2e connector. I've noticed that I still had the old plugin dependency in my pom :

```
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
```

I've switched to the updated version and the plugin is correctly discovered with it :

```
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
```